# Eventkit Cannot Access Calendar

Tags: objective-c, ios, permissions, calendar, eventkit

I cannot access my device's calendar using Eventkit. I am using a EKEventEditViewController to present a view for adding a calendar entry.

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEventEditViewController *eventController = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc]init]; 
eventController.eventStore = eventStore;
eventController.editViewDelegate = self;

...

[self presentViewController:eventController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This **works fine on the simulator** but I get the following **error message when running it on the phone** (iOS6): *"This app does not have access to your calendars"*

[image: This app does not have access to your calendars]

Checking the privacy settings as advised doesn't show any entry at all for my app.

How to solve this and grant access?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can request access

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];    
if([store respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        /* This code will run when uses has made his/her choice */
    }];
}
```

You can also add a key to the plist (NSCalendarsUsageDescription) that will display a string when requesting said access.

Comment: I've seen this callback get called outside of main thread, caused issues for me until i caught that.